# Concatenating __FILE__ and __LINE__ macros in C++

Tags: c++

I want my exception messages to contain information about the exception location.

So I would like to have something like this:

```
#define LOCATION __FILE__ " : " __LINE__

throw std::exception(std::string("ABCD. ") + LOCATION);
```

That define is obviously incorrect. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Note: You could simplify the exception construction to `std::exception( "ABCD." LOCATION )`.

Comment: you may have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739102/concatenating-strings-in-macros-c

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You need to expand that macro in two levels:

```
#define S1(x) #x
#define S2(x) S1(x)
#define LOCATION __FILE__ " : " S2(__LINE__)
```

Here is the reason:

You need expand `__LINE__` in two levels, before passing it to `#x`.

First of all, using operator `#` in a *function-like* macro, it has to be followed by a macro *parameter* but `__LINE__` is not a parameter, so compiler complains it's a stray operator.

On the other hand, `__LINE__` itself is a macro and contains current line number, it should be expanded to the number before using it with `#`, otherwise, you will get string `"__LINE__"` instead of a number.

Macro `S2(__LINE__)` expands `__LINE__` to a line number, then we pass the line number to `#x`.

Comment: What if I want to add __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ as a third one? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Boost's [`BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(__LINE__)`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/stringize.html) does that, in case you don't want to create your own macros S1 and S2.

Comment: @sree: #define LOCATION std::string(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__) + " :: " + std::string(__FILE__) + ":" + std::string(S2(__LINE__))

Comment: @adiog While to OP asked for a string for an exception, i.e. used in a function, you get an error with your proposal here: `char foo[] = LOCATION;` at file scope as well as in a function.