# Casting (converting) number in a format with multiple dots (a version number) to string

Tags: c++, string

```
#define EXTERNAL_API_VERSION 1.12.1
std::string version = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(EXTERNAL_API_VERSION);
```

This code generates a compilation error:

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before 'constant'
error C2059: syntax error : ')'
```

Are there any simple alternatives for casting number in such format (more then one dot) to string?

Comment: `1.12.1` isn't a valid literal constant.

Comment: It's not a valid lexeme in C++, so no it's not possible. The only way to have versions in code is as strings.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster you are right, but i have to cast it to string :-)

Comment: @Sanich Then why not make it a string to begin with?

Comment: What's wrong with `const char* EXTERNAL_API_VERSION = "1.12.1";`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg The define {EXTERNAL_API_VERSION}  is defined in external API. Can't touch that code.

Comment: @juanchopanza and what's wrong with `const std::string EXTERNAL_API_VERSION("1.12.1");` ;)

Comment: Whose idea was it to define `EXTERNAL_API_VERSION` that way? This question seems to be the only Google hit for that identifier. BTW, I believe it's a valid token sequence: a floating-point constant `1.12`, followed by `.`, followed by an integer constant `1`. That sequence can't appear after preprocessing in a syntactically valid program, though ([you can't overload `.`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/520035/827263)), so that doesn't do you much good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without touching `EXTERNAL_API_VERSION`, you need to expand that marco in two levels to a string literal:

```
#define S(X) #X
#define STR(X) S(X)

std::string version = STR(EXTERNAL_API_VERSION);
```

Comment: @Sanich: In first step you expand `EXTERNAL_API_VERSION` to `1.12.1`, in the next step you make it a string literal by `#`, `"1.12.1"`. You can not mix these two step in one. It's useful to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19343239/952747)