# Including line number and filename in a string variable

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005

Is there an easy way to build a string which includes the `_FILE_` and `_LINE_` values?

I could do something like:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "Error in "<<_FILE_<<":"<<_LINE_<<" - too many bees!";
log(ss.str());
```

But that is a PITA, compared to the ideal which might be:

```
log("Error in "+_FILE_+":"+_LINE_+" - too many bees!");
```

Is there a neat way to do this in C++/STL/boost? Note I am limited to older compiler, no C++11!

Comment: btw, should be `__FILE__` and `__LINE__`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19343205/c-concatenating-file-and-line-macros

Comment: I see questions with single and double underscores, also `_line` - do all versions exist or are people just lazy when typing?

Comment: @AlexFarber same basic question but no full answer (working code example is provided) If someone provides one to either question that would be ideal.

Comment: Mostly, people macroize their log calls to make this easy by baking in the boilerplate.

Comment: @John which part of the log message do you need to be customizable? I doubt you want to keep typing `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` everytime you want to log something.

Comment: @AlexFarber I didn't believe I could use `+` to build a string in-place this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Alex commented: double macro expansion to make `__LINE__` into a string and let the compiler concatenate the strings for you:

```
#define S(x) #x
#define S_(x) S(x)
#define S__LINE__ S_(__LINE__)

log("Error in "__FILE__":"S__LINE__" - too many bees!");
```

to reduce typing, as greatwolf suggested:

```
#define logfl(s) log("Error in "__FILE__":"S__LINE__" - "s)

logfl("too many bees!");
```

Comment: I also find it quite useful to #define log to some function returning ostream&, then you can log all kind of objects there